# Can I get the original file name of an attachement loaded from a web form via jetty?

Tags: jetty, apache-camel

I'm using camel-jetty for simple file upload. jetty issues a form, collects the response and creates an attachement. I have a camel processor which processes the attachement.

My problem is the getName() method of the DataHandler gives me something like:

D:folderfilename.zip

ie, its removed all the \ characters from the file path. (Yes, the browser is running on windows).

Is there any configuration I can use to find out the original filename?

This is Camel 2.8 or 2.9 and jetty 7.4.5.

If its a bug, I'll raise it in Jetty, but I was wondering if I'm doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted this for now by using the header for the form item.